# Remove vertical glyph on WPF MenuItem

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a simple WPF ContextMenu with a MenuItem. I now want to hide the vertical line between the icon and the item text from code behind for this first MenuItem only, so I don't want to create a completely new template.

```
System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu menu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
menu.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
menu.PlacementTarget = myButton;

MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.Header = "My MenuItem";
item.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
item.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

menu.Items.Add(item);
menu.IsOpen = true;
```

I already tried to modify the template in the Loaded-event of the MenuItem, but unfortunately the MenuItem doesn't change and if I try to call the ApplyTemplate method manually, it returns false.

Comment: The [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747082(v=vs.90).aspx) for the menu item contains a `Border` around the **Check Mark**. Try getting hold of that border and setting the `BorderThickness` to 0.

Comment: Which checkmark? Where/ from which event or method should I access and modify the ControlTemplate. As already mentioned, I tried to modify the ControlTemplate in the Loaded-event of the MenuItem and it also changes, but the look of the MenuItem doesn't change. So that's the problem.